# Callback with XPCOM

Tags: c++, xpcom, xulrunner

I would like to implement the observer pattern similar to Timer component. Instead of calling a callback by time expiration, the callbacks that are observers of a topic would be called from system events (like new file created, or a new e-mail received, etc.). I tried using nsIObserverService in the component XPCOM, but it seems that functions from component aren't able to call observers in JavaScript by using NotifyObservers. The NotifyObservers only works when is called from JavaScript.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect your code was wrong.  `nsIObserverService` should work just fine here.

Comment: Well, it is possible. I recognize that something is wrong, but it unclear to me what is wrong.
Code: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/VCQjuHg2pE
Header: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/FBtiY42Fuy
IDL: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/DP4cTNYD4c
JS Example: http://paste.ideaslabs.com/show/UxdYXQUo82
No error is showed when "mycomp.observe" is called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Example::Example` always runs on the main thread (because it's being created by your script). So it never creates a proxy to the observer service. But the call to `Example::Call` from `Ex::Run` happens on the background thread, and I think in this case the call to `NotifyObservers` returns `NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED` (which you ignore).